# SQL Check If Value Changed (Including from or to NULL)

Tags: sql, select, null, compare, where-clause

I have an SQL query where I'm needing to do a comparison of one value to another value by checking if they're inequivalent. This means my WHERE clause carries out a validation if val1 is not equal to val2, i.e.

```
SELECT
. . .
WHERE val1 != val2
```

I'm aware Standard SQL-92 states that both `!=` and `<>` will not work for `NULL`, meaning the above logic carrying out something like `3 != NULL` will NOT return true like one might expect

My question is, how can I alter this WHERE to check for value changes also considering NULL?

In this case, both val1 or val2 could be `NULL` and they could be setting to and from `NULL` so I don't believe I can't run a comparison such as `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` in a straightforward way since I'll be unsure of whether the incoming val1 or val2 are already going to be `NULL` or not.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably you just need `or val1 is null or val2 is null`

Comment: The SQL Standard defines this operator as `IS DISTINCT FROM`. For example `col1 is distinct from colb`. The implementation depends on the specific database. Which one are you using?

Comment: @TheImpaler Ah I was unaware of such an operator, let me look into that. Also this is a Snowflake db

Comment: not sure, but maybe something like WHERE val1<>val2 OR (val1 IS NULL AND val2 IS NOT NULL) OR(val1 IS NOT NULL AND val2 IS NULL)

Comment: Wrap the input in function to provide alternative value in case of Null. In SQLServer that would be IsNull(). In Access it would be Nz(). Add tag for RDBMS used.